# Android Studio: "App not installed" error while generating signed apk for updating existing app

Tags: android, android-studio, signed-apk

I have generated a signed apk for updating the existing app in google store. For testing successful installation, I tried installing the generated apk in my mobile. But it shows "App not installed". I generated the signed apk with the same jks file and key that I used for previous version and followed the steps given in https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/generate-signed-apk-android-studio.html. What I am missing here?

[I have added the gradle.build screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd6A2.png)

Comment: Please attach your build.gradle file for your app and check whether the app is signed correctly.

Comment: The app is signed correctly. I checked

Comment: Please check the gradle file and tell what changes should i make

Comment: First of all is app installed correctly if you uninstall the previous version?

Comment: I didnt uninstall the previous version of the app.

Comment: Okey, then try to install the app on a fresh device. If your app cannot be installed it is a build problem, if it is installed on a fresh device then it is signature problem

Comment: Ok i will try. Thank you

Comment: Is the version of app installed on your device currently is DEBUG version??

Comment: No! it is installed from playstore

Comment: I tried what you said. When i uninstal the previous version and install the currect update it is working fine. Only trying update over the current installed version is failing. So it is a signature problem. And what can be done to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

App is not signed correctly. You have to be sure that you have checked Signature versions correctly as in previous version.. 
See this screen shot [image]

Comment: Yes i tried checking both the checkboxes. But still error persists.

Comment: try v2 (Full APK Signature) only

Comment: Also try clean project before making build.. and if app is already installed try delete it and then try!